# How do i run a "git rev-parse" on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm writing an API that's using django-rest-framework (but the framework, nor the language matter at this point).  I've got a diagnostic API endpoint "/version" that reads some data from a file (the last git checkin ID) and then spits it back out.  the code looks like this:

```
class Version(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)

    def get(self, request):
        git_version_file = open('gitversion', 'r')
        checkin_id = git_version_file.read().strip()
        return Response({'version' : checkin_id})
```

Normally (on my dev machine) this is easy as I can call a git post-commit hook to create the file (the command would be `git rev-parse --short HEAD > gitversion`. Obviously, this file cannot be checked into git.

However, I want this to work on my instances that are deployed on heroku.  Of course, I can use the "heroku releases" command, however I want this to be available programmatically (by people who don't have access to the "heroku" command line command).

I can't run this on a one-off dyno as the filesystems are not the same.  I'm not sure how I can accomplish this at this point.